# Connect to Google Cloud Datastore from nodejs (seneca)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to the Google Cloud Datastore using node.js and the data layer functionality present in the Seneca framework. The Seneca framework needs to create a connection to a database as per connecting to a database instance, passing information like:

```
name: '',
host: '',
port: ,
username: '',
password: ''
```

etc.

Is there a way to connect to a Google Datastore like a typcal database instance or is the only way through REST api calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the only way to connect to the Google Cloud Datastore, using node.js, is by using the REST API.

Using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) you can get access to a datastore object:

```
googleapis.discover('datastore', 'v1beta2')
    .withAuthClient(authCredentials)
    .execute(function(err, client) {
      if (err) {
        seneca.log.error(err);
      }
      datastore = client.datastore.withDefaultParams({
        datasetId: datasetid}).datasets;
    });
```

This object will be like your connection object and you can use this object to make [queries](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) to your datastore.

The [seneca](http://senecajs.org/) datastore plugin I wrote can be found [here](https://github.com/jrochenrfm/seneca-googledata-store)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication support for Google Cloud Datastore is currently limited to OAuth 2.0. See [Getting started with Google Cloud Datastore and Node.js](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/).

The credentials are passed along in each HTTP request.